# Does the spinning of a nucleus alter its charge distribution?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I put a nucleus in a magnetic field. It spins. Does the electric charge distribution remain homogeneous or does the charge redistribute? Can this be measured? Will accept reference as answer.

Comment: Nuclei that have non-zero angular momentum are spinning without regard to your putting it into a magnetic field. Experimentally you put them into a field to get access to the polarized observable that you need to measure the effects of that rotation. And yes, they deform and yes it can be measured. Sid Harris even did a cartoon on it... Essentially any nuclear physics book should cover this, but my copy of Walecka is in storage right now, and my Perkins never came back from loan.

Comment: I put this: 'deformation of nucleus in magnetic field' into Google and this was the first hit: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Shape_deformations_in_atomic_nuclei

Comment: I know that nuclei can deform. I am asking if the electric charge distribution remains homogeneous.

Comment: The charge distribution more or less follows the mass distribution.

Comment: dmckee: But that is exactly my question. Do you have a reference? What happens in a magnetic field?